# SQL Replication for Schema changes

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

I want to configure the snapshot replication for all the articles. The problem iam facing is first time all the articles got sync on the subscriber. But later on let suppose if there is a schema change (added new table) in the publisher that newly created table is not getting replicated on the subscriber.

So every time if there a schema changes in publisher i have to manually update the selected articles on the publisher to get it replicated on the subscriber.

Is there a way to automate this step that whenever there is a schema changes at the publisher (added new articles) it should be automatically replicated on the subscriber ? Thanks

Comment: You would need to switch to transactional replication to have this kind of automation.  Otherwise the subscriber will get the latest changes after a new snapshot has been taken.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to automate this step?

Sure.  You can write a proc that uses [sp_helparticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helparticle-transact-sql) to compare the articles with the sys.tables, and then runs [sp_addarticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql) to add articles for the new tables.

But there's no replication setting that will do this for you.